# sql loop update with multiple rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got to update a column value by decreasing the value in the column by a variable.

There are two conditions:
1. where the row count = 1
2. where the row count is more than 1

I've got it set to do the single row count but need help when the query returns multiple rows.

```
set @rowsCounted = (select COUNT(QuantityA) from Offers where WID = @wId and ND = @nd)

if(@rowsCounted = 1)
 begin
  set @QuantityAvailable = (select QuantityA from Offers where WID = @wId and ND = @nd)
  set @QuantityAvailable = (select @QuantityAvailable - @QuantityAdjusted)
  update Offers
   set QuantityA = @QuantityAvailable
   where WID = @wId and ND = @nd
 end
else
 begin
  select @rowsCounted as rowsCounted -- example of 4 rows with values of  = 287,280,288,288
--begin loop as the QuantityA may contain different values

 end
```

Comment: I know this is not always the right answer, but why wouldn't you just do that in one SQL statement, instead of updating one row at a time?

Comment: i used the 1 row option; however, each row may have a different quantity value. so i may have row 1 with 280 and i need to decrease by 1 = 279; row 2 may be 288 and i need to decrease by 1 = 287.

Comment: so my thought was get the row 1 qty value and modify it; then get the 2nd row qty and modify it. this way the update can handle different qty values and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Could you post sample data and the desired update results? Most likely this can be done in a set-based fashion which will perform much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@QuantityAdjusted` is constant for the procedure, then you only need one update statement. Use set-based thought constructs rather than procedural-based ones:

```
update Offers
   set QuantityA = QuantityA - @QuantityAdjusted
   where WID = @wId and ND = @nd
```

This will update in a set-based operation, and there is no need to construct your own loop. This is part of what SQL engines are meant to do.